# Difference between Swift shell and Swift compiled

Tags: swift, compilation

I'm new to swift and today I wrote a small script to test it for scientific application. 
Regarding the small application I wrote, it appears that it is slower than C++ but faster than python. However, I noticed that, if I run my application using the interpreter (like from terminal swift main.swift) or I compile it, there is no difference in the execution time.

Am I missing something or is it normal. I would have expected a considerable speed-up in the compiled version. Here the sample code:

```
    import Foundation

    func isPrime(num:Int) -> Int {

         var IsPrime = 0
         var count = 1

         for index in 1...num-1 {

        if (num % index != 0) {
            ++count

        }

    }

    if (count == num-1) {

        IsPrime = 1
    }

    return IsPrime

}


   var isReallyPrime = 0
   var maxNum = 10000
   print(isPrime(21))

let methodStart = NSDate()

var primeArray = [Int]()

for index in 2...maxNum-1 {

    if (index%1000 == 0) {

        print("Iterarion   \(index)")

    }

    if (isPrime(index) == 1) {
        primeArray.append(index)
    }
}

   let methodFinish = NSDate()
   let executionTime = methodFinish.timeIntervalSinceDate(methodStart)


var last =  primeArray.last
print("Last prime number:  \(last)")
print("Execution time [s]: \(executionTime)")
```

Comment: In Xcode you're running a debug executable with all kinds of goodies baked in to ease development. You can look up on google how to tweak optimization settings, how to switch your scheme to use a release build, and how to skip the debug info on build.

Answer (score 1):

```
swift main.swift
```

compiles the Swift code and then runs it. So the only overhead compared to  a compiled binary is that the code is compiled on every invocation.

You can even pass compiler options such as the optimization level:

```
swift -Onone main.swift
swift -O main.swift 
swift -Ounchecked main.swift
```